# Implementing popup modal - where to export constructor DialogService

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I am making a CRUD ASP.NET Core application with angular 2 and typescript.

Before trying to implement the popup I had this output:
[image]

Now I'm trying to put the "Insert or edit student details" table inside a popup modal while still keeping the inserting and editing functionality. 
I'm using [ng2-bootstrap-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-bootstrap-modal).

I made a modify.component.ts and I imported the ModifyComponent component in my app.module.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DialogComponent, DialogService } from "ng2-bootstrap-modal";
export interface ModifyModel {
  title:string;
  message:string;
}
@Component({  
    selector: 'modify',
    template: `<div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                   <div class="modal-header">
                     <button type="button" class="close" (click)="close()" >&times;</button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title">{{title || 'Confirm'}}</h4>
  <!-- Here's the insert or edit table code --> 
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="modify()">OK</button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="close()" >Cancel</button>
                   </div>
                 </div>
              </div>`
})
export class ModifyComponent extends DialogComponent<ModifyModel, boolean> implements ModifyModel {
  title: string;
  message: string;
  constructor(dialogService: DialogService) {
    super(dialogService);
  }
  modify() {
    // we set dialog result as true on click on confirm button, 
    // then we can get dialog result from caller code 
    this.result = true;
    this.close();
  }
}
```

I then imported the ModifyComponent into the students.component.ts where I'd like to use it.

This also contains all the code to insert/edit data from my database. Here's the code for it so far:

```js
import {
    Component, Input, trigger,
    state,
    style,
    transition,
    animate,
    keyframes
} from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { ModifyComponent } from '../students/modify.component';
import { DialogService } from "ng2-bootstrap-modal";
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
    selector: 'students',
    template: require('./students.component.html')
})

export class studentsComponent {
    // to get the Student Details  
    public student: StudentMasters[] = [];
    // To stored Student Informations for insert/Update and Delete  
    public StdIDs = "0";
    public StdNames = "";
    public Emails = "";
    public Phones = "";
    public Addresss = "";

    //To display Edit and Delete Images  
    public imgEdit = require("./Images/edit.gif");
    public imgDelete = require("./Images/delete.gif");

    constructor(public http: Http) {
        this.getData();
    }

    //to get all the Student data from Web API  
    getData() {
        this.http.get('/api/StudentMastersAPI/Student').subscribe(result => {
            this.student = result.json();
        });
    }


    // to show form to add new Student Information  
    AddStudent() {
        this.StdIDs = "0";
        this.StdNames = "";
        this.Emails = "";
        this.Phones = "";
        this.Addresss = "";
    }

    // to show form to edit Student Information  
    editStudentsDetails(StdID, StdName, Email, Phone, Address) {
        this.StdIDs = StdID;
        this.StdNames = StdName;
        this.Emails = Email;
        this.Phones = Phone;
        this.Addresss = Address;
    }

    // If the studentid is 0 then insert the student infromation using post and if the student id is more than 0 then edit using put mehod  
    addStudentsDetails(StdID, StdName, Email, Phone, Address) {
        alert(StdName);
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        if (StdID == 0) {
            this.http.post('api/StudentMastersAPI', JSON.stringify({ StdID: StdID, StdName: StdName, Email: Email, Phone: Phone, Address: Address }), { headers: headers }).subscribe();
            alert("Student Detail Inserted");
        }
        else {
            this.http.put('api/StudentMastersAPI/' + StdID, JSON.stringify({ StdID: StdID, StdName: StdName, Email: Email, Phone: Phone, Address: Address }), { headers: headers }).subscribe();
            alert("Student Detail Updated");
        }
        this.getData();
    }

    //to Delete the selected student detail from database  
    deleteStudentsDetails(StdID) {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        this.http.delete('api/StudentMastersAPI/' + StdID, { headers: headers }).subscribe();
        alert("Student Detail Deleted");
        this.getData();
    }

    closeEdits() {
        this.StdIDs = "0";
        this.StdNames = "";
        this.Emails = "";
        this.Phones = "";
        this.Addresss = "";
    }


}

export interface StudentMasters {
    stdID: number;
    stdName: string;
    email: string;
    phone: string;
    address: string;
}
```

I put the button code in my students.component.html.

Now the only thing I'm missing is to export the constructor DialogService in the students.component.ts.

```js
        constructor(private dialogService:DialogService) {}
        showModify() {
            let disposable = this.dialogService.addDialog(ModifyComponent, {
                title:'Confirm title', 
                message:'Confirm message'})
                .subscribe((isConfirmed)=>{
                    //We get dialog result
                    if(isConfirmed) {
                        alert('accepted');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('declined');
                    }
                });
            setTimeout(()=>{
                disposable.unsubscribe();
            },10000);
        }
    }
```

I tried putting this under "export class studentsComponent {" but I get an error that I'm not allowed to use multiple constructors (I'm already using constructor(public http: Http) to get the data from my database).

**Where do I export the DialogService constructor?** 
Do I need to make a separate export?

I'll provide any more information as soon as possible if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding it in brackets of the first constructor.

```
    constructor(public http: Http, private dialogService: DialogService) {
    this.getData();   }
```

And putting the showModify() code in the studentComponent.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it @Injectable and put in providers section in app.module.ts. Please refer to this text https://long2know.com/2017/01/angular2-dialogservice-exploring-bootstrap-part-2/

Comment: I tried to implement it from your link. Please see added part at the bottom of the post.

Comment: But you have exported DialogComponent instead of dialog service. In the link there is custom implementation of the DialogService. Either import in app.module DialogComponent because you have exported that as @Injectable not DialogService, either just use DialogService instead. If you did not implemented DialogService anywhere you have to use modalService: NgbModal directly in your components

Answer (score 0):

You should not create service manually as this breaks concepts on dependency injection that Angular2 is based on.

You need to add your service to `prividers` declaration in your @NgModule class (if you want to have single service instance in your application) or to `providers` declaration in your `studentsComponent` class if you want to have instance per component. All other work Angular2 will make for you.

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
     DialogService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I tried to implement this but having some trouble. Please see added part at the bottom of the main post.

Comment: Try use different names. You have `export class DialogService {}` and `private service: DialogService` as dependency. Both have same names and you have conflicts then

Comment: I updated the edited part of the pain post. I'm not sure how to export DialogService now.